Limud HaTorah in Mitzrayim
The Satmar Rav in Divrei Yoel (Parshas Vayigash, p. 480; left column) explains how Yaakov Avinu and his family were, halachically, able to leave Eretz Yisroel and settle in Mitzrayim although it is forbidden to settle in a country run by idol worshipers and heretics. The Satmar Rav says:

As for someone leaving the Land of Israel to go to outside lands, it
is considered as if they are serving foreign gods. However, this is
not the case when holiness is present in the foreign rule, as was the
case during Joseph's time in Egypt. On the contrary, during the time
of the Canaanites, they served foreign rulers. At that time, Yosef
was placed over Egypt, and his rule was sanctified. The verse states,
'G-d has made me a ruler of all Egypt.' Thus, the rule in Egypt was
considered holy, according to the promise given: 'Do not be afraid to
go down to Egypt, for there I will make you a great nation.'

He then says:

In this context, the greatness of the nation is attributed to their
merit in studying the Torah, as stated: 'Who is like the great
nation?' Israel is called a great nation because they upheld the Torah
and its commandments. As our sages said, in Egypt, Israel continued to
study Torah, and even Yehudah was engaged in Torah study. It is also
mentioned that a Yeshiva (a place of Torah study) was established in
Egypt, and Amram, the elder, sat there.

We know from Rashi (Bereishis 46:28) that the words "להורת לפניו – Lehoros Lefanav" mean:

לפניו BEFORE HIM — means before he should arrive there. A Midrashic
comment is: להורת לפניו (in the sense of, “that there might be
teaching before him”) — to establish for him a House of Study from
which Teaching (הוראה or תורה) might go forth (Genesis Rabbah 95:3).

But.... The navi Yechezkel (20:8, see Rashi there) says:

But they rebelled against me, and would not hearken to me: they did not cast away every man the abominations of their eyes, neither did they forsake the idols of Miżrayim: then I said, I will pour out my fury upon them, to accomplish my anger against them in the midst of the land of Miżrayim.
But they rebelled against Me They are the wicked, the majority of
Israel, who died in the three days of darkness, as it is said (Exod.
13:18): “and the children of Israel went out of Egypt,
(חֲמֻשִּׁים)”one out of fifty, and some say, one out of five hundred.
(Rashi)

The Satmar Rav says that even in Mitzrayim, the Jewish people continued to study Torah. How to reconcile this with what the Navi Yechezkel says? Are there clear sources that say that Yisroel was studying Torah in Egypt? And if so, how to reconcile that with the teachings that B'nei Yisroel were sunken to the -49th level of impurity?
We know from different source (Daas Zkenim) that since the Torah did not cease from shevet Levi, they were not enslaved (שלא פסקה מהם תורה כלל ולפיכך לא נשתעבדו במצרים), but this applies only to Shevet Levi.

Easy. There was a yeshiva and Amram was the only student by the end.

Do you realize that Jewish education is not scientific and does not attempt to describe historical reality? Rather, rabbinic sermons are motivational and inspirational. They aspire to give a sense of tradition, continuation, holiness, etc. As we have archeological evidence for Yechezkel's claims, we can assume he was reflecting a harsh reality about idolatry, that many try to wipe under the carpet. Note the "להורות לפניו" does not MEAN to establish Yeshivos, but IS INTERPRETED as such.

@ClintEastwood but do we have traditions on how many people led Torah-lives back then?

Of course! You just posted your tradition from the Satmar Rav!

I think you misunderstood my question. I proposed, based on the Satmar Rav, that " Israel continued to study Torah in Mitzrayim". Yet, there are sources that say they were on the -49th level of tumah and there even was avodah zarah. My question was how to reconcile that. Was there really a high amount of Limud HaTorah, of only in the Yeshivot and in "important families"?

A very relevant source, and maybe even an answer, is the Rambam's description (Hil. Avodah Zarah 1:3, near the end): "When the Jews extended their stay in Egypt, however, they learned from the [Egyptians'] deeds and began worshiping the stars as they did, with the exception of the tribe of Levi, who clung to the mitzvot of the patriarchs - the tribe of Levi never served false gods."

The answer to your question maybe is similar to R. Yom-Tov Schwarz' explaination regarding the generation of Bayis Sheini, which I quoted in the discussion why Jerusalem got destroyed. According to him, Hashem ensures that the merits of those who observe the commandments and study Torah completely balance the misdeeds of those who have fallen off the derekh. In other words there were two groups of Jews in every shevet: those who kept emunah and acted with bitachon vs. those who did not. The problem might arise only when those who keep the mitzvos make them blemished, like we had senseless hatred during Bayis Sheini.
Here's the midrash Tanchuma Beshalach 1 partially quoted by Rashi:

And the children of Israel went up armed (Exod. 13:18). This suggests that only one out of five (hamishah) went up armed (hamushim). However, others say: Only one out of fifty (hamishim) went up, while still others insist that only one out of every five hundred (mihamesh) went up. R. Nehorai declared: By the Temple service! Not even one out of five thousand went up. When had the others died? During the days of darkness, they would bring their dead for burial while the Egyptians sat in darkness. The Israelites praised Him and thanked Him (for the fact) that their enemies were unable to see their misfortune and take satisfaction in it.

The midrash can be viewed as exactly proving the point of R. Yom-Tov Schwarz. It does not mean the p'shat that 80% of Jews died in Mitzraim, for entire Mitzraim in those days did not have over 10-15 mln people including the Jews. The midrash is talking about percentages of the Jews who had the intent to serve Hashem at different levels lishma. For example, the fraction 1/5,000 for a count of 600,000 signifies 10 people per shevet who were really learned and were full tzadikim, while the fraction 1/5 signifies 10,000 people per shevet, who just accepted the concept of leaving Mitraim to serve Hashem.
As a side note, when reading your question some people may ask: we know that Mitzrayim was a center of witchcraft and idol worship, even if run by Yosef, why was it necessary for Jews to go there? It turns out from the studies by archaeologists, the mitzrim were extremely serious about their religion. It was this kind of attitude that Hashem wanted the Jewish people to have when performing  the mitzvos. However, this matter is tangential to your question.
Finally, in regards to the fact that Bnei Yehuda learned Torah in Mitzraim, we have a pasuk in Divrei haYamim A 2:6:

וּבְנֵ֣י זֶ֗רַח זִ֠מְרִ֠י וְאֵיתָ֧ן וְהֵימָ֛ן וְכַלְכֹּ֥ל וָדָ֖רַע כֻּלָּ֥ם חֲמִשָּֽׁה׃
The sons of Zerah (ben Yehuda): Zimri, Ethan, Heman, Calcol, and Dara, five in all.

Evidently these five sons lived in Mitzraim. Rashi explains futher:

and Ethan, and Heman, and Calcol, and Dara They all lived at the time of David and at the time of Solomon, and they were exceedingly wise. Concerning this it says (I Kings 5:11): “And he was wiser than all men, than Ethan the Ezrahite, and Heman, and Calcol, and Darda, the sons of Mahol.” Further on, regarding Solomon’s wisdom, the expression is “Darda,” for even though it was called the generation of knowledge (דֵּעָה דּוּר) because of its wisdom, Solomon was wiser than all of them. Now when Scripture says הָאֶזְרָחִי, the “aleph” is superfluous, like הַזַּרְחִי (Num. 26:20), [because] he was descended from Zerah, and in many places, the “aleph” is inserted into the word, and is not pronounced, e.g. (Job. 13:17): “and my speech (וְאַחְוָתִי)” (Isa. 19:6): “And they shall abandon (וְהֶאֶזְנִיחוּ).” And likewise, (Num. 11:4): “וְְהָאסַפְסוּף, and the rabble.” Now sometimes it is completely missing, as (II Sam. 19:14): “תֹמְרוּ, you shall say,” and likewise, (II Chron. 22:5): “... and the Arameans (הָרַמִּים) smote.” [The verse in Kings] is expounded by Pesikta (Peskikta d’Rav Kahana p. 34, Pesikta Rabbathi 14:9): “... than all men this refers to Adam. Ethan is Abraham. Heman is Moses. Calcol is Joseph. Darda is the generation of the desert. Mahol means that He forgave them for making the Calf.”

One might think that they were descendands of Zerach. However, Bamidbar Rabba 14 teaches regarding the summary of the offerings of Nesiim:

“Five rams” (Numbers 7:17) – it corresponds to the five mighty ones of the world, and they are: “The sons of Zeraḥ: Zimri, Eitan, Heiman, Kalkol, and Dara; all of them were five” (I Chronicles 2:6).

In other words, this is the example of great Torah scholars from Mitzraim, since the Nesiim brought offerings beginning on the 1st of Nissan, one year after Exodus, when people could not have learned the Torah well unless they had a tradition.

Wonderful. So even if one tribe continued to study Torah and did mitzvos, the greater part of the shevatim did not. But what about the Satmar Rav's statement: "As our sages said, in Egypt, Israel continued to study Torah, and even Yehudah was engaged in Torah study." - but based on the sources, it was only Shevet Levi (see also Avodat HaMelekh on Mishneh Torah, Foreign Worship and Customs of the Nations 1:3:20). What statement of our Chazal does the Satmar Rav references to?

@Shmuel Thank you! I think we may find chazal for Shevet Yehuda also. I do not have answer right now, but here are the possible places to look. 1. the lineage of David at the end of megilas Rus (I saw a statement they were all wholesome, including those who were in Mitzraim). 2. The wife of Aharon haKohein (ben Amram) was Elisheva, sister of Nachshon ben Aminadav from shevet Yehudah.

@Shmuel I added something that I found. Maybe there is more?
